# Get min DateTime from Linq

Tags: linq

How can I convert this linq query to single line?

```
var closets = (from v in options
               select v.ExceriseDate).Min();

var option = options.Where(v => v.ExceriseDate == closets).Single();

return option;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
options.OrderBy(v => v.ExceriseDate).First();
```

I'll also add that you don't want to use `Single()` unless you can guarantee it will be unique. It will throw an exception if more than one exist. That would happen if two if your objects shared the same `ExceriseDate`. Lastly if you prefer the query syntax for Linq over the expression method:

```
var option = (from v in options
              orderby v.ExceriseDate
              select v).First();
```

Comment: I want to return the option object and not the DateTime